# What difference between Dsl and Builder classes for mapping some Drafts?

Tags: commercetools

I have such a question about mapping Draft through the DSL classes and Builder classes.

For example:

`CustomerDraftDsl` and `CustomerDraftBuilder`

What difference between this approaches except that Builder classes has method build()? Some of them works faster or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CustomerDraftDsl

The outcome of both is to build a `SphereRequest`. `CustomerDraftDsl` is an immutable data structure, so if you use a either you get a new instance like a modified copy.

### CustomerDraftBuilder

`CustomerDraftBuilder` is a classic mutable builder where the parameter methods return the same instance. So there are two variants to support different programming paradigms.